# Query no result

Tags: php, mysql

I've got no result from this query. Am I doing some thing wrong?

```
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_url FROM tvb_users WHERE ID = '$currentAuthor->ID'") or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.\n<br />Query: " . $query . "<br />\nError: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
        $query2 = $query['user_url'];
        echo "$query2";
```

(For wordpress)

Comment: You need to fetch the result set.

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_array($query); then $user_url= $row['user_url'];

Answer (score 2):

If you are using wordpress I recommend using their WPDB object to make your life easier: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb